# NSMutableData initWithCapacity absurd capacity?

Tags: ios, download, nsmutabledata

I have these methods that handle a download

But there is an error when initialize  NSMutableData

```
NSNumber *filesize;
NSMutableData *data;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    filesize = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[response expectedContentLength]];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)recievedData {


    if (data==nil) {
        data =  [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[filesize floatValue]];
    }


    [data appendData:recievedData];
    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data length]]; //MAGIC
    float progress = [resourceLength floatValue] / [filesize floatValue];
    progressBar.progress = progress;



}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error "
                                                        message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    connection1=nil;
    [connection1 cancel];



}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

}
```

Here generates error

**data =  [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[filesize floatValue]];**

> **[NSConcreteMutableData initWithCapacity:]: absurd capacity: 4294967295, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes'**

Comment: Shouldn't that be `initWithCapacity:[filesize unsignedIntValue]`?

Comment: I try but I still marked the same error. What I can do?

Comment: See @Codo's thorough answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `NSURLResponse expectedContentLength` doesn't know the length, it will return -1 (the documentation says `NSURLResponseUnknownLength`, which is a constant initialized to -1).

You then use a funny way to go from `long long` (result type of `NSURLResponse expectedContentLength`) via `NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger` and `NSNumber floatValue` to `NSUInteger` (argument to `NSMutableData initWithCapacity:`). The result is that -1 (internally represented as 0xffffffff) ends up as  4294967295 (internally represented as 0xffffffff as well).

You have to test for `NSURLResponseUnknownLength` and use a different initial capacity in that case. And don't use `NSNumber`. Simply convert the signed `long long` into an unsigned `NSUInteger` if it's within the reasonable range.